# Data Space Used not matching docker images output

Tags: docker, storage, space, device-mapper

The output for docker info shows that I'm using 515.1 GB of 622.8 GB

```
$ docker info
.
.
Server Version: 1.13.0
Storage Driver: devicemapper
 Pool Name: vg-thinpool
 Pool Blocksize: 524.3 kB
 Base Device Size: 10.74 GB
 Backing Filesystem: xfs
 Data file:
 Metadata file:
 Data Space Used: 515.1 GB
 Data Space Total: 622.8 GB
 Data Space Available: 107.7 GB
 Metadata Space Used: 161.5 MB
 Metadata Space Total: 6.442 GB
 Metadata Space Available: 6.281 GB
 Thin Pool Minimum Free Space: 62.28 GB
.
.
.
```

However `docker images` , `docker volume ls` & `docker ps` show that I don't have anything stored locally. Is there any reason this could be happening?

```
$ docker images -a
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE

$ docker volume ls
DRIVER              VOLUME NAME

$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE              COMMAND              CREATED             STATUS                         PORTS                                              NAMES
```

Comment: Have you made any change in the storage driver recently (or `userns-remap`)?

Comment: I haven't, I've been using devicemapper since the start. And no, I haven't touched `userns-remap`

Is there a way I can mount the logical volume onto the host so I can take a look at what is using the space on the volume?

Comment: I have never used devicemapper driver so I cant answer you that. You can try to use `mount`, `vgdisplay` or `pvdisplay` to gather more info